# Как использовать атрибуты маршрутизации?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

у меня есть следующий *контроллер*

```
[RoutePrefix("Operation")]
public class OperationController: Controller
{
    [Route("{operationId}/AddAct")]
    public ActionResult AddAct(int operationId){}

    [Route("Act/{actId}/Edit")]
    public ActionResult EditAct(int actId){}

    [Route("{operationId}/Details")]
    public ActionResult GetDetails(int operationId){}
}
```

ссылка на метод `GetDetails` принимает следующий вид `Operation/2385/Details`, `AddAct` - `Operation/2385/AddAct`

представлени `Details` частично формируется *динамически*(средствами `ajax` запросов):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
    <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Программы", "GetProgramList", "Operation", new { operationId = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Tabs" }, new { @data_target = "#Tabs", @data_toggle = "tab" } )</li>
    @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Акты", "GetActList", "Operation", new { operationId = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Tabs" }, new { @data_target = "#Tabs", @data_toggle = "tab" })</li>
    }
    <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Файлы", "GetAttachmentList", "Operation", new { operationId = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Tabs" }, new { @data_target="#Tabs", @data_toggle = "tab" } )</li>
</ul>
<div id="Tabs"></div>
```

т.е. в соответствии с кликом пользователя по *вкладке* подгружается необходимое частичное представление

вот так например выглядит представление для отображения *списка актов*:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Number)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.State)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comment)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="Act/@item.Id/Edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Проблема возникает при попытке редактирования акта, сервер возвращает:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>   Разыскиваемый вами ресурс был удален, было изменено его имя или он временно недоступен.

Ссылка на метод в *адресной строке* браузера вроде корректная:

***`http://localhost:58482/Operation/2385/Act/974/Edit`***

если же использовать *html helper* `Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditAct", new {actId = item.Id})` то тогда ошибок не происходит.

Подскажите что я делаю не правильно.

Comment: ссылка как раз не корректная: `Operation/Act/{actId}/Edit`

Comment: адреса лучше с помощью хелпера Url генерируй а не вручную прописывай

Comment: `Operation/Act/{actId}/Edit` - right, `Operation/2385/Act/974/Edit` - wrong, сравни по сегментам и найди лишний :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по прописанным атрибутам, действию *EditAct* соответствует адрес

```
Operation/Act/{actId}/Edit
```

В то же время в ручной ссылке прописан адрес

```
Act/@item.Id/Edit
```

Который при переходе со страницы Details

```
Operation/{operationId}/Details
```

Приведет к переходу на страницу

```
Operation/{operationId}/Act/@item.Id/Edit
```

Что в свою очередь отличается от описанного в роуте

```
Operation/Act/{actId}/Edit
Operation/{operationId}/Act/@item.Id/Edit
```

Автоматически создаваемая ссылка работает, так как возвращает абсолютный путь, а не относительный.

Для исправления можно либо дописать параметр *operationId* в роут для `Edit`, либо использовать [хелпер Url](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx), либо уже используемый [Html.ActionLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx)

Для предупреждения таких ошибок, в случае если параметр нужен во всех методах контроллера, его лучше вынести в *RoutePrefix*

```
[RoutePrefix("Operation/{operationId}")]
```

Тогда отпадет необходимость дописывать его в каждом методе

```
[RoutePrefix("Operation/{operationId}")]
public class OperationController: Controller
{
    [Route("AddAct")]
    public ActionResult AddAct(int operationId){}

    [Route("Act/{actId}/Edit")]
    public ActionResult EditAct(int actId){}

    [Route("Details")]
    public ActionResult GetDetails(int operationId){}
}
```

Comment: а не мог бы ты уточнить как быть с методами у которых `operationId` отсутствует, например метод который возвращает список операций или добавляет новую операцию?

Comment: @Bald, для сброса можно использовать `~`, тогда префикс проигнорируется: `[Route("~/Operation/List")]` : [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5 : Route Prefixes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/#route-prefixes)